# Remove Space between the Content in Horizontal FlatList React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to have 10 images in horizontal FlatList with height of device screen and no space between the images but the problem is i am getting space in between the images below is the code :

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      data:[
        {
          image:require('./assets/images/2.jpg')
        },
        {
          image:require('./assets/images/1.jpg')
        },
        {
          image:require('./assets/images/3.jpg')
        },
        {
          image:require('./assets/images/4.jpg')
        },
        {
          image:require('./assets/images/5.jpg')
        },
        {
          image:require('./assets/images/7.jpg')
        },
        {
          image:require('./assets/images/8.jpg')
        },
        {
          image:require('./assets/images/9.jpg')
        },
        {
          image:require('./assets/images/10.jpg')
        },

      ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
    var {
      width,
      height
    } = Dimensions.get('window');

    return (
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={this.state.data}
        style={{height:this.height}}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return (
            <View  >
                <Image style={{flex:1}} resizeMode='contain' source={item.image}  />
            </View>
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item,index)=>item.image}
      />
    );
  }
```

tried different things like contentContainerStyle but that is also not working.

Comment: Can you add the code [here](https://snack.expo.io) ?

Comment: Did you look at the docs? properties like [getItemLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#getitemlayout) might be of use here

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/rk4sw_ATG

Comment: no getItemLayout is also not working